# Facebook URL sharer

Tags: facebook, url, share

I know, facebook url sharer is deprecated, but i'd like to know why these two URLs whicht to me seems identical doesn't work in the same way

in this the image is not loaded:
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p%5Burl%5D=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bookextracts.it%2Fdetails_book.php%3Fid%3D1020&p%5Bimages%5D%5B0%5D=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bookextracts.it%2Fupload%2Fcover%2F9788806212438_1365147078.jpg&p%5Btitle%5D=Il+panico+quotidiano

int this the image is loaded:
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p%5Burl%5D=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bookextracts.it%2Fdetails_book.php%3Fid%3D1044&p%5Bimages%5D%5B0%5D=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bookextracts.it%2Fupload%2Fcover%2F9788809781795_1365749254.jpg&p%5Btitle%5D=Sette+diavoli

Comment: It looks as though the first doesn't have a thumbnail associated with it? Can you see the thumbnail if you go to this location in some other way?

Comment: these are the two thumbs that should be loaded:
http://www.bookextracts.it/upload/cover/9788806212438_1365147078.jpg
http://www.bookextracts.it/upload/cover/9788809781795_1365749254.jpg